# Combine Objects in a js array without overwriting them

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an array like below

```
 [
    {
        "202229": "8.418"
    },
    {
        "202229": null
    },
    {
        "202229": null
    },
    {
        "202230": "10.713"
    },
    {
        "202230": "0.859"
    }
 ]
```

i want to convert it to below structure

```
[
    { 
        "202229": "8.418",
        "202229": null,
        "202229": null,
        "202230": "10.713",
        "202230": "0.859"
    }
]
```

Note that values are not overwritten and keys `"202229"` etc are dynamic . I tried using reduce methods but i couldn't get it in this format . Any help would be appreciated . Thanks

Comment: you can not have same named properties in a single object.

Comment: It’s okay if it splits across two objects. [
    [{ 
        "202229": "8.418",
        "202230": null  },{
        "202229": null,
        “202230:”2333”,
        "202231": "10.713"
    }]
 Is good too

Comment: why not three objects? what goes wrong?

Comment: It can. My main aim is to have  work week (202229, etc) and it’s value in  one object. Instead of having each object for every work week I want it to be  one object for  all the work week and it’s value. This essentially  represents one row

Comment: Why do you want to combine same keys "without overriding  them"? What's the purpose of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disperse the keys to various objects.

```js
const
    data = [{ 202229: "8.418" }, { 202229: null }, { 202229: null }, { 202230: "10.713" }, { 202230: "0.859" }, { 202231: "0.503" }, { 202231: null }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            let i = 0;
            while (k in (r[i] ??= {})) i++;
            r[i][k] = v;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Is this the expected output?

Comment: @Maf, yes, assuming to the op ...

Comment: SO the question should be updated, cause that's not very clear. What's the purpose of this?

Comment: My apologies. I’ll correct the question. I essentially wanted to have all workweek data  in one objects rather than individual object for every work week and it’s value. This transformed data is passed to AG grid.